# Retype code but retain existing interface

Tags: go, interface, code-generation

I would like to retype an existing type but retain its interface inheritance.

so example code:

```
interface interface1 {
  func interfaceFunc1()
}

type basicStruct struct {
  param int
}

type retyped1 basicStruct
type retyped2 basicStruct

func (basicStruct) interfaceFunc1() {
  // does stuff
}

func getTyped1() retyped1 {
  return basicStruct{param:0}
}

func getTyped2() retyped2 {
  return basicStruct{param:1}
}

func main() {
  type1 := getTyped1()
  type2 := getTyped2()

  // These lines do not compile
  type1.interfaceFunc1()
  type2.interfaceFunc1()
}
```

Due to a code generation library I am using I can't just have it return basic struct it has to return retyped1 and retyped2.
But I also need to use the interface functions.
Is there anyway to use the interface functions without some silly copy and paste of all the interface functions which do the exact same thing except like 1 if statement in a couple hundred lines?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It's hard to tell exactly what your issue is here - I'm not sure what you mean by "interface functions", and there is no such thing as "interface inheritance" in Go.

Comment: Can you use type aliases instead, like `type retyped1 = basicStruct`?

Comment: Just convert to basicStruct: https://play.golang.org/p/31vzfYMIIrX

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkinThat worked!  If you make it as an answer I can accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Burak Serdar pointed, in `golang` there is 2 different ways to define type:

```
type retyped1 struct {
  basicStruct
}
```

Which inherits methods of `basicStruct`, and

```
type retyped2 basicStruct
```

Which creates new struct with same fields as `basicStruct`, but not it's methods.

For your particular situation you could use [type aliases](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/18130-type-alias.md), which is actually just another name for type, so you can reuse it's methods with it:

```
type retyped1 = basicStruct
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to define a type based on an existing struct preserving its interface, use embedding:

```
type basicStruct struct {
  param int
}

type derivedStruct1 struct {
  basicStruct
}

type derivedType2 basicStruct
```

Above `derivedStruct1` has the same methods as `basicStruct` and satisfies the same interfaces, but `derivedType2` does not have any methods.

Comment: This does in fact work!  But for my case the type aliases ended up working better